# cosmos db document query takes long time

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

i am new to cosmos-db and facing issues in querying the collection, i have a partitioned collection with 100000 RU/s(unlimited storage capacity). the partition is based on '/Bid' which a GUID. i am querying the collection based on the partition key value which has 10,000 records (the collection has more than 28,942,445 documents for different partitions). i am using  the following query to get the documents but it takes around 50 seconds to execute the query which is not feasible.

```
object partitionkey = new object();

partitionkey = "2359c59a-f730-40df-865c-d4e161189f5b";

// Now execute the same query via direct SQL

 var  DistinctBColumn = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<BColumn>(BordereauxColumnCollection.SelfLink, "SELECT * FROM BColumn_UL c WHERE c.BId = '2359c59a-f730-40df-865c-d4e161189f5b'",new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery=true, PartitionKey= new PartitionKey("2359c59a-f730-40df-865c-d4e161189f5b") }, partitionkey).ToList();
```

also tried with other querying options which too resulted in talking along 50 seconds. 
But it takes less than a second for the same query on azure portal.
kindly help to optimize the query and correct me if i am wrong. Many Thanks.

Comment: Is the name of your partition key attribute `BId`?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes

Comment: Since you're already querying on a partition key, can you try by disabling `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` i.e. do something like `EnableCrossPartitionQuery=false` in your FeedOptions?

Comment: if i don't use `FeedOptions` it throws the following error `Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception`

Comment: What is your connection mode in ConnectionPolicy? here is an example

 connectionPolicy.ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct;
 connectionPolicy.ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp;

Comment: Please make sure you fire the query after constructing a singleton client ... read some more tips here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips

Comment: @RafatSarosh applied `connectionPolicy`  to the code but it did not affect the execution time in my case.

Comment: did you play with MaxDegreeOfParallelism, MaxBufferedItemCount as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips